# How to filter elements in ng repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of elements with names and values that I want to filter in a ng-repeat tag. My array has elements like that :

```
$scope.extensions = [{
  name: "extension1.00",
  value: 1234587
}, {
  name: "extension1.02",
  value: 665873698742136544
}, {
  name: "extension2.00",
  value: 11
}........ //other elements
]
```

And my ng-repeat tag is the following :

```
<div ng-repeat = "extension in ( extensions | filter : myFilter(extension.name)  | orderBy: 'name' ) ">
```

And what I want to do is to write a custom filter to display ONLY elements whose name doesn't end with ".00". So, in the example above, I should only see "extension1.02" and not the two others.

So, I tried to write the simple filter just to not display the first element ("extension1.00") :

```
$scope.myFilter = function(name) {
  return function(item) {
    var result = true;
    if (item === "extension1.00") {
      return false;
    } else {
    }

    return result;
  };
};
```

But it didn't work at all...
Finally, Here is my code : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/8oMCgFJhDaFyXfnz2OzU?p=preview

I tried to write my own filter but I have no idea how can I achieve this.
Can you help me please to write that filter? Thank you!

Comment: Please include the code for `myFilter()` in the question.

Comment: `function myFilter(name) { return name.substr(-3) != '.00'; }`

Comment: @Soviut I add the filter now !

Comment: You have assigned the filter directly as a scope variable which is not correct.you have to register the filter using the filter factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a working example here --> [click here](http://codepen.io/FlyingBananas/pen/QGyXaL)

The biggest mistake you did, was to hold the filter function inside the controller.

My filter function:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function(){
 return function(items, str){
  var filtered = [];
  angular.forEach(items, function(item){
    if (item.name.substr(item.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1) !== str){
    filtered.push(item);
  }
});
return filtered;}});
```

Check out the link to the codepen.. it shows a bit more custom filter that you can work with :)

Comment: Very much similar to my idea.This is how to code ideally,making it more generic.+1 for it.Also add how to configure ng-repeat for further user reference.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace following code

```
<div ng-repeat = "extension in ( extensions | filter : myFilter(extension.name)  | orderBy: 'name' ) ">
```

with

```
<div ng-repeat = "extension in extensions | filter : {name: '!.00'}  | orderBy: 'name'  ">
```

And also remove myFilter method from your controller you won't need that now

Following code will fulfill your requirement

Change myFilter method in controller with following code

```
$scope.myFilter = function(extension) {
var extArr = [];
extArr =  extension.name.split(".");

 if(parseInt(extArr[1]) === 0){
  return false; 
}else{
 return true;
}};
```

And in HTML replace with following code

```
<div ng-repeat = "extension in  extensions | filter : myFilter  | orderBy: 'name'  ">
```

Comment: It's a better idea than mine but it doesn't work completely. Because if you have for example "extension1.002" you will remove it also !! You're just checking if the name doesn't CONTAIN the sequence ".00" but what I want to remove is the ones which END with that sequence

Comment: Actually according to your question I figured out that you need to filter out ".00" part only.

Comment: Then, can you tell me how can I correct that please?

Comment: Check if updated code help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use the standard filter property to do this  particular task.As the extension of your idea i would recommend to write a custom filter to do so.

Here is the sample code snippet of the custom filter

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).filter("myFilter", function () {
            return function (data) {
                var myValues = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (!(data[i]["name"].endsWith(".00"))) {

                        myValues.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }
                return myValues;
            }
        });
```

To configure the ng-repeat directive do as follows.

```
<div ng-repeat="extension in  extensions | mySampleFilter | orderBy: 'name'">
  {{extension.name}}
</div>
```